# WCF Service Call Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wrapper

What is best practice for creating wrapper for WCF service call? I think it is necessary 
 to monitor all calls in the same place, I am thinking to use this kind of code, is this right idea?

```
RetType t = ServiceExecutionContext<IServiceChanel>.Execute(s=>s.GetServiceMethod());
```

What kind of wrapper are you use in your enterprise applications?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think most people don't use wrappers at all. Please elaborate on why you want to use them, and why you think everyone uses them.

Comment: I don't think everyone uses them, but I think it is necessary to have all kind of service exception handling and service call logging,for example,in the same place... isn't it?

Comment: If it were "necessary", then it would be in the framework. Even if it were in the framework, it might not be done through wrappers. Seriously, have you seen anyone else talk about creating wrappers for everything? If not, thne you're the first. Did you think you were likely to be the first to find something "necessary"? After three years that WCF has been out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WCF has a model that allows you to be in the service call chain.  I would use that rather than trying to wrap every service call if all that you are trying to do is some logging (which WCF is already very good at doing if you turn diagnostics on in the config file) and common things like that around your service calls.

[Here is a good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx) about how to create custom behaviors for WCF services.

Comment: I read the article, but I saw nothing concerning the problem of a WCF service that could throw an exception on dispose. Would you recommand a service wrapper for handling that bad Dispose implementation?

Comment: We just use convention.  It is a well known situation, and fairly easy to debug.  A wrapper is an option, but it is just as much convention to use a wrapper as it is to call Dispose in a try catch block instead of a using block.  just my .02

Answer (score 1):

If you need to, write your own [Message Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).

WCF also has [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) builtin.  By default, you can log easily to a file using the System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, however if you need to write the log elsewhere (say, a database), you could write your own [trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172718.aspx).

I would recommend this approach over a message inspector... message inspectors are too easy to write incorrectly and hurt performance without knowing what you are doing.