# Generic method to wrap a function

Tags: c#, wrapper

Say I want to wrap a function in another function, so to add some functionality to the wrapped function. But I don't know the return type or parameters on beforehand as the methods are generated as a web service proxy.

My first train of thought was using `Func<T>`. But some functions might return void, in which case `Action<T>` would be more appropriate.

Now my question: is there a nice generic way to achieve this? Is there some pattern I need to look for?

Comment: So you're trying to wrap a proxy?  In another proxy?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example together with your rationale here.

Comment: VS allows you to generate a service reference, I need to add some functionality to every method. Put differently, I think I'm looking for a generic way of implementing the decorator pattern (if my vocabulary is right). Not knowing the return type and/or parameter list.

Comment: @sebt - still need more info.  *What functionality* do you need to add to every method and why???

Comment: @RQDQ, basically it comes down to timing related functionality.

Comment: @sebst - for crying out loud just tell us what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to time service calls?  Are you trying to introduce latency?

Comment: As @RQDQ suggests in his answer, I thought of Facade ...possibly, as you state, Decorator may be the technique. Without some concrete examples of what you're trying to accomplish, a good answer might be difficult to assess.

Comment: @RQDQ yes, im trying to time service calls. I compose a series of related service calls who together form some business process. Currently I generate some code and manually write a wrapper with the timing functionality. I would like this to be more generic, possibly some code generation. Delegating functionality using Func<T> and Action<T> was my first thought, but since I can't know how the methods look like, I need a generic way of generating this wrapper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Service Call Wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944562/wcf-service-call-wrapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) comes to mind... It's not a very automatic way of doing things, but it works.  You basically just put another interface in front of the proxy and call that instead.  You can then add any functionality that you desire.

Another way to approach this is with [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).  I've used [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (when it was free) to do this this in the past.  You can do things like add Pre / Post processing in the function by adding an attribute to a method / property.  The AOP components then use code weaving to rewrite your IL to include the code that you've referenced.  Note that this can significantly slow the build process.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, company was closed during the holidays :)
After talking things over with a colleague we decided to settle on T4 code generation. Though AOP will be drawing our attention in the (near) future as well.

Comment: Another area to look at is WMI performance counters... I don't have direct experience with the WCF specific counters, but that might be a low impedance way to get some stats (especially considering there are so many tools available to deal with perf counters).

Answer (score 2):

As you say "I don't know the return type or parameters on beforehand", I think a **Dynamic Proxy** is what you 
need.

Unfortunately, I know about the Dynamic Proxy in Java only. But I am sure, there is something similar for C#.

Try Googling "Dynamic Proxy C#".

For example, there seems to be an implementation for C# here: http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/

**So, what IS a Dynamic Proxy?**

From the JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html#api:

> A dynamic proxy class is a class that **implements a list of interfaces specified at runtime** such that a method invocation through one of the interfaces on an instance of the class will be encoded and dispatched to another object through a uniform interface. Thus, a dynamic proxy class can be used to create a type-safe proxy object for a list of interfaces **without requiring pre-generation** of the proxy class, such as with compile-time tools. Method invocations on an instance of a dynamic proxy class are dispatched to a **single method in the instance's invocation handler**, and they are encoded with a java.lang.reflect.Method object identifying the method that was invoked and an array of type Object containing the arguments.